# How to preserve timezone aware timestamps when converting from pandas to koalas to CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, spark-koalas

How do I make Koalas preserve timezone information in a timezone-aware pandas Timestamp?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pds = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2018-11-06T14:00:00+00:00')])
>>> pds
0   2018-11-06 14:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

See how it includes the `+00:00` on the end, and dtype is `datetime64[ns, UTC]`.  This is how I want it.

Now I convert it to koalas:

```
>>> import databricks.koalas as ks
>>> kss = ks.from_pandas(pds)
kss
0   2018-11-06 08:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It has lost the timezone information, and has subtracted 6 hours.  Not sure why, since I am in US CDT, you would think it would **ADD 5** hours rather than **SUBCTRACT 6**.  And furthermore, now when I write it to CSV:

```
>>> kss.to_csv('output.csv')
```

It subtracts **another six hours** by appending `-06:00`:

```
2018-11-06T08:00:00.000-06:00
```

So after going from pandas -> koalas -> CSV my timestamp has lost 12 full hours: what started out as `2018-11-06 14:00:00+00:00` has become `2018-11-06T08:00:00.000-06:00`

Comment: 8 h on UTC-6 is 14 h UTC, so I think you don't loose hours. Nevertheless, this shouldn't happen; tz info should be preserved.

Comment: oh yeah, you're right, my brain wasn't working... but yes the question remains on how to preserve tz info in koalas